# Boldface CSV headings

Tags: csv, csvsimple

(*question updated from 1 to 3 columns*)

I am trying to do something supremely simple: typeset a table such as

**what.csv**

```
First,Last,Style
Bob,Marley,Reggae
Fritz,Wunderlich,Lieder
```

with boldface headings.

[image: CSV table]

Yet in the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\section{---One---}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
  \hline
  \bfseries Name
  \\\hline
  \csvreader[head to column names]{what.csv}{}
        {\First \Last \Style \\}
\end{tabular}

\section{---Two---}
\csvautotabular{what.csv}

\section{---Three---}
% \csvautobooktabular{what.csv}

\end{document}
```

various attempts at eliminating the extra emtpy entry fail. Indeed just adding the closing bottom line is tricky.

I'd gladly settle for some preset style, one applying `\bfseries` for the headings (and without frequent horizontal lines). Using `\csvautotabular` works (minus the boldface), but `\csvautobooktabular` doesn't. Adding `\bfseries`  as an option also fail. Is `csvsimple` the right tool for the job in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In the following MWE, I have replaced `\begin{tabular}{|c|}` with the `tabular=|c|` option, used `table head=\hline\bfseries Name\\\hline,` for the top line, the bold column header and the line below the header as well as `table foot = \hline` for the horizontal line at the end of the table. I have also added a second variant using the horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs} %% Only needed for the second example.
\begin{document}

\csvreader[head to column names,%
           tabular=|c|,%
           table head=\hline\bfseries Name\\\hline,%
           table foot = \hline]%
           {who.csv}%
           {}%
           {\Name}

\bigskip

\csvreader[head to column names,%
           tabular=c,%
           table head=\toprule\bfseries Name\\\midrule,%
           table foot = \bottomrule]%
           {who.csv}%
           {}%
           {\Name}

\end{document}
```

---

Updae regarding the changed `what.csv`:

With

```
First,Last,Style
Bob,Marley,Reggae
Fritz,Wunderlich,Lieder
```

you can use the following MWE to get a two column tabular that contains the first and last name:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\csvreader[head to column names,%
           tabular=cc,%
           table head=\toprule\bfseries First & \bfseries Last\\\midrule,%
           table foot = \bottomrule]%
           {who.csv}%
           {}%
           {\First & \Last}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! Though apparently moving to just two (`First`, `Last`) columns cannot simply be done by replacing the lines with `tabular=c c,%` and `{\First \Last}`. Could you add a hint?

Comment: @Vrokipal: I have updated my answer regarding your edited csv file.

Comment: I see. We're actually plugging in into tabular.